# Best way to access the values of std::multimap?

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap

I have multiple `std::multimap` of same keys and different values. I would like to access the values of each `std::multimap` at one place. What would be the best approach to do this.

```
multimap<int, double> data1;
multimap<int, string> data2;
multimap<int, int> data3;
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if(i%2 == 0) {
        data1.insert(make_pair(i,10.0));
    }
    else {
        data1.insert(make_pair(0,10.0));
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    sting temp = "String Value" + to_string(i);
    if(i%2 == 0) {
        data2.insert(make_pair(i,temp));
    }
    else {
        data2.insert(make_pair(0,temp));
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if(i%2 == 0) {
        data3.insert(make_pair(i,i));
    }
    else {
        data1.insert(make_pair(0,i*i));
    }
}
for(const auto& mp: data1) {
    // Now I want to access data of all multimap here of key mp.first
}
```

I thought about `std::find` function but it's not going to work here, becuase there keys are being repeated multiple times.

Also suggest some better datastructure to approach this problem.

Comment: Why not a single `multimap<int, mystruct>`?

Comment: @MooingDuck : I never thought about it. It's definately going to work here, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Mooning Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845092/mooing-duck) in the comment section of my question. Using `std::multimap<int,mystruct>` is best option for me.

```
struct mystruct {
    int value;
    string name;
    double score;
} ;
```

And the values can be access in usual struct way.